# WP is_front_page and displaying images

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm working on a new WordPress theme (haven't touched WP themes since like 2.8...) and I'm attempting to make an if/else statement that changes the behavior of my top navigation bar based on whether the page is a front_page or not.

Essentially what I'm after is if the page is a front_page, then display the logo image. If the page is any other kind of page, then display a simple H1 element with the company name:

```
<li class="name">
    <?php
        if (is_front_page()) {
            echo '<a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>';
            echo '<img src="' .bloginfo( "template_directory" ). '/images/logo-dsi.png" alt="DSI" />';
            echo '</a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="' .home_url(). '">';
            echo '<h1 class="logo">DSI</h1>';
            echo '</a>';
        }
    ?>
</li>
```

The else statement is working fine. But my if statement is not producing the img tag correctly. It echoes the literal bloginfo('template_directory') url and not inserting that into the img src, which is what I want it to do. It's trying to find an image at this url: localhost/images/logo-dsi.png

Obviously my syntax on line 5 is wrong somewhere, but I'm also not sure if I'm going about this the right way. Is there a better solution to what I'm trying to accomplish here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The later is correct however

```
echo '<a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>';
```

Should be

```
echo '<a href="' . bloginfo("url") . '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out and it worked:

```
<li class="name">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
        <?php
            if (is_front_page()) { ?>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo-dsi.png" alt="DSI" />

            <?php
            } else { ?>
                <h1 class="logo">DSI</h1>
            <?php } ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Apologies, I should have hacked away at it a little longer. But maybe this will become helpful to someone else.

I knew echos in WordPress looked bad for a reason... ;-)

Also I'm sure there's a prettier way to write this out, but for now, that code does the trick.